# Multiple DB Objects from Multiple flat files in SSDT/SSIS For Each Loop Container

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I'm very new to SQLSever/SSDT/SSIS etc, but not SQL or programming in general. From reading on the web I have been able to build myself a loop program in SSDT/SSIS that reads in all flat files in a directory and creates a database item.

The only issue is I am not sure how to set up a connection string/parametrise the database part of the loop. When I execute the package to run I can see from the job log that it is looping through the flat files as expected, but it is loading everything into a single DB object.

I am unable to find anything online that tells me how to create DB objects sequentially the are named the same as the flat file read in. Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm not even sure at the minute how to grab code from the package to post on here, so if anyone could assist, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a separate database object for each flat file?  If they're in the same format, it's better to load all of them into a common database table, perhaps setting a "Source" column using a variable, to indicate where each row/set of rows in the table came fromt.

Comment: will that table not become massive and difficult to work with?

Comment: Yes.  That's kind of the point of a database table: to become massive but easy to work with.  Especially if you index it properly, you can pull out just the rows you want to work with in microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a variable FileName.

If you read multiple files, I suppose, you use the Foreach File Enumerator in your loop.

Then, add your variable in 'variable mappings'

[image: variablesMapping]

Finally, you can use this variable (in your loop) everywhere to create DBObjects (in a query for example).